# Removing Empty Pages in a PDF document using C#

Tags: c#, pdf, selectpdf

I have a PDF file with more than 500 pages, but it has few empty pages with in the document in a random manner. Is there any possible way to remove these empty pages? The system which generates PDF, uses select PDF library (http://selectpdf.com/pdf-library-for-net/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For remove pdf same page use `PdfDocument` class [`RemovePage`](http://selectpdf.com/docs/M_SelectPdf_PdfDocument_RemovePage.htm) or [`RemovePageAt`](http://selectpdf.com/docs/M_SelectPdf_PdfDocument_RemovePageAt.htm) methods.